# python I tried to change 'while-loop' to 'for-loop' but it didn't get same result

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

**This is 'while' code**

```
 ##전역변수 선언 부분##
i,k=0,0

##메인코드 부분##

i=0
while i<9:
    if i<5:
        k=0
        while k<4-i:
            print('  ', end='')
            k+=1
        k=0
        while k<i*2+1:
            print('\u2665', end='')
```

**and I changed this 'while' to 'for' but isnt same result :(**

```
 ##전역변수 선언 부분##
i,k=0,0

##메인코드 부분##

for i in range(0,9):
    if i<5:
        for k in range(0,4-i):
            print('  ',end='')
            k+=1
        for k in range(0,i*2+1):
            print('\u2665',end='')
```

Comment: The first loop doesn't change `i`.  The second does (via the `for` statement).  Also, the `k+=1` assignment serves no purpose in the second version, since `k` gets set by the `for` statement each time through.  And the second `k` loop in the first version never changes `k`.  Basically none of this code makes sense.

Comment: When I try the `while` code, I get an infinite loop. Is that actually what you want? The reason for the infinite loop is that inside `while k<i*2+1:`, neither `k` nor `i` changes.

Comment: In the second code, `k` changes in `for k in range(0,i*2+1):`, because *that is how `for` loops work*. You *do not need* `k += 1`, and in fact it will have no useful effect; every time through the loop, `k` is set to the next value from the `range(0,i*2+1)`. Make sure you understand here that `range` is *not special syntax*; it is *just a function* that creates an iterable sequence. As an example, try: `for k in 'example': print(k)`.

Comment: yes i want infinite loop but sencond coding's result isnt

Comment: To make an infinite loop with `for`, you need an unlimited iterable. It is a little tricky to create these, but it is possible with only built-in functions: `iter(lambda: True,  False)` for example. Another way is by writing a generator, or by using `itertools.count` from the standard library.

Comment: thx I need study about 'iter'

Comment: can you show an example of the outputs that you want? I get that you want an infinite loop but then why have a range for `i` if it never changes?